# How to update a field/value inside a model?

Tags: syntax, record, elm

If my model looks like:

```
type alias Application = { id : Int , term : Int , amount : Int }  
type alias Model = { application : Application }
```

and I am trying to update the `term` value, I have `onInput UpdateTerm` on an input inside my update case statement how do I update this value?

so far I have `UpdateTerm term ->;` but unsure how I can update only the `term` value inside application?

Answer (score 6):

Record field update is described in the [guide](https://guide.elm-lang.org/core_language.html) and also in the [reference documentation](https://elm-lang.org/docs/syntax#records). Updating a field in a record nested inside another record is simply a matter of doing one after the other. Assuming you have a binding named `model`:

```
let
    application =
        model.application

    updatedApplication =
        { application | term = term }
in
{ model | application = updatedApplication }
```

Answer (score 1):

for a better readability you can make function like this:

```
update msg model = 
    case msg of
       changeNestedProperty property -> 
            ({ model | record= setNestedProperty property model.record } , Cmd.none)

setNestedProperty : String -> Record-> Record
setNestedProperty property record = 
   { record | nestedProperty = property }
```